# Constraint layout Guideline java.lang.AssertionError: BOTTOM

Tags: android, imageview, android-constraintlayout, constraintlayout-guideline

I have an ImageView and I want it to have height of the 40% of the screen height. I am trying to accomplish it by constraint layout's guidelines, but I get runtime error "java.lang.AssertionError: BOTTOM". I think the error is that image becomes higher than screen's 40%, but I don't know how to fix the bug. here is my xml code.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/apartment_main_image_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/apart"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/first_horizontal_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/first_horizontal_guideline"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4"/>
```

Comment: try `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/first_horizontal_guideline"` in `imageView` and  `android:layout_width="0dp"`
    `android:layout_height="0dp"` in guideline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because you forgot to add the `orientation` of the Guideline You can give an orientation of the guideline according to your requirement `horizontal` or `vertical`

When you use a vertical guideline, any view constrained to it should do it horizontally and the same thing for horizontal guidelines.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/apartment_main_image_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/apart"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/first_horizontal_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/first_horizontal_guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent` to set height according to screen and no need to use a guideline.

**Example code**

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/apartment_main_image_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/apart"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't added the android:orientation="horizontal" attribute use this code

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/first_horizontal_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.40" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use layout constraint Height percent to set height and remove the bottom to bottom command
or
you need 40% of hegith so you can do it by constraint height percentage and make width match parent

[For more info and clarification check out the link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout)